# Can’t select vertices on torus

Tags: vertices, selection-tools

I am very new to blender and can’t select vertices on any shapes/objects. I am in edit & vertex mode. When I click on the torus it doesn’t turn grey, it stays orange. When I click on a vertex with the pointer, nothing happens. My torus is the only thing selected on the grid. I am trying to shape the torus but can’t because of this conflict. It won’t let me select any edges when i’m in edge mode or faces when i’m in face mode either. I have tried to press control & tab but when I do and switch my mode & then click the vertexes, edges, or faces,still, nothing happens. Please help me! [image][image]

Comment: Please use a proper screenshot tool rather than taking photos of your screen. Also could you show more of the UI so we can see what settings you may have on/off etc?

Answer (score 1):

Orange marks everything that is selected. You can press Alt + A (Blender 2.8) or A (Blender 2.79) to deselect everything and then click on whatever edge or face you want to select. Keybindings have changed between these two Blender versions, which can cause some confusion.

[image: Fully selected torus]Fully selected torus, press Alt + A to deselect
[image: Deselected torus]Select faces by left clicking (Blender 2.8) or right click (Blender 2.79)
[image: Selected face]